# average computing without using sum function in python?

Tags: python, average

I'm trying to solve a python code for reading a text file then select some similar text, then collect the float numbers from them and count their average, **without using the SUM function**.

but I have a column of list of the average of each number with its before numbers! and the last one is my answer but I cannot select the last character as the python looks at it as one columnar strange number!

**this is my code :**

```
count = 0
total = 0

while True:   
    inp = raw_input ("Enter file name: ")
    if inp == 'myfile.txt' : break

fh = open(inp)
for line in fh:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line.startswith("my_pattern") :
        count = count + 1
        sb = line.split()
        sc = sb[1]    # this gaves me the numbers only from eavh line #
        value = float(sc)

        total = total + value
        average = total/count
        print average
```

the answer:

```
0.8475     (*this is exactly the first number, I mean it is the average of just one number, Itself !*)
0.73265     (*this is the average of two numbers, the second number and the number 0.8475*)
0.728447368421
0.727035
0.728385714286
0.726895454545
0.725547826087
0.7268
0.737112     (this is the answer, but I do not want a column of numbers and by the way, I could not split just this number)
```

Comment: The fact that you are printing the average value *exactly the same number of times as there are lines* should give you a big hint as to what is happening. Look closely at the indentation of your `print average` line; what do you think would happen if you unindented that a level?

Comment: it says : name 'average' is not defined !

Comment: You need to put it outside the `for` loop, and add `average = 0` before the loop to account for the possibility that there are no matching lines in your file.

Comment: "lokks at it as one columnar strange number"???

Comment: Dear Martijn, thank you ! it works!

Comment: of course i could not understand that what was wrong?                                I was assuming that because I have collect the numbers in the "if statement" which is located in the "for" loop, I must run all my mathematical procedure under the for" loop part of my code. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing the average calculated *so far* each time you find a matching line.

This is why you get the running average; for the first line, there is only one value, so the average of one value is that value. You print again when you updated the average for the second line, etc.

You only need to calculate the average when you have collected the total for *all* lines. When iterating over the file, you only need to count the number of matching lines and update the `total` value.

Put your average calculation *outside* the `for` loop. Take into account there could be 0 matching lines:

```
for line in fh:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line.startswith("my_pattern") :
        count = count + 1
        sb = line.split()
        sc = sb[1]    # this gaves me the numbers only from eavh line #
        value = float(sc)
        total = total + value

if count:
    average = total / count
    print average
```